# Testing for italics with Capybara

Tags: capybara

Could anyone suggest the best way to look for italics on a page with capybara. I have a feature test that searches for a specific piece of text within a page. This text is in italics and is also a different colour from everything else on the page. I thought looking for italics would be preferable to searching for a colour value but i am unsure how to do either.

```
    <div class="text-control">
  <p class="body">Test text is here and then<i>italics</i> are there</p>
</div>
```

The feature test is written as follows:

```
Then(/^the word should be highlighted in the example sentence$/) do
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like just need to check that the sentence, the `p` element, contains the word, the `i` element. To do this you can do:

```
# Get the element containing the sentence
sentence_element = find('p.body')

# Check that the sentence includes the italics element with a specific text
expect(sentence_element).to have_css('i', text: 'italics')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assert a text is present in the particular element, sounds reasonable... you can do that using the suggesting by Justin...

Test a text is in italic... that's not a test you want to add in this layer of testing or in any layer in fact...